# after insert data in database not able to redirect to html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#rec").click( function() {                                 
    $.post($("#ne").attr("action"), $("#ne :input").serializeArray(), function(info) { 
        $("#out").html(desc);  
    });  
});  

$("#ne").submit(function() {  
    return false;  
});
```

`rec` is the id of the HTML form and `out` is the id of a span tag in the same page as the form, i am not able to redirect after inserting record ?

Comment: You're preventing the form from submitting.

Comment: Based on your code, it doesn't seem you actually want to do a redirect, since why else would you modify the code on the page after the post. Can you please give a better explanation of your problem and desired behavior?

Comment: how i prevent form form submitting ?

Comment: i want to redirect from jquey not directly with form

Comment: You're preventing it using return false. What you want is actually unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
window.location.reload();
```

or

```
window.location = "add your link here";
```

or

```
$(this).attr("href","add your page link here");
```

or

```
window.location.replace("add your page link here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this methods

// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect

window.location.replace("http://yoursite.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link

window.location.href = "http://yoursite.com";